# ORDER BY ordena pela primeira casa e não pelo numero em si

Tags: php, mysql

eu estou puxando valores com order by e eles não estão certos nem em ASC ou DESC.

O código meu é esse, como posso arrumar esse erro?

```
$sql = 'SELECT *, Player.ID AS ID, LEFT(FirstName,1) AS FirstName, FirstName AS FName FROM Player INNER JOIN OverallRatings ON OverallRatings.PID = Player.ID INNER JOIN franchises ON franchises.GameID = Player.CurrentTeamID '.$where.' ORDER BY '.$sort.' '.$by.' LIMIT 250';
```

Print da ordem.

[image: print da ordem]

Comment: E qual o tipo de dado do campo utilizado para ordenação? Provavelmente não é numérico.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como o @Leandro comentou, se quer ordenar numericamente, o melhor seria mudar o tipo do campo para numérico (integer por exemplo).

Um solução alternativa, desde que a tabela não seja muito grande, é converter o campo para numérico no momento da ordenação, usando [`CONVERT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_convert) por exemplo:

`$sort = convert(nome-do-campo, signed integer)`

Veja aqui um exemplo funcionando: [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0eaf3/6)

Answer (score 1):

Olá, Maycon. Tudo bem?
Você precisa mudar o tipo de campo na sua tabela para int. No exemplo que você colocou está como texto (char, varchar, text).

Quando você utiliza ordenação em campo texto ele irá considerar a ordenação alfabética. Com isto, quando vc tem 1,12,11,9 para a ordenação ficaria 1,11,12,9. Pois iniciou primeiro a que estava com 1 e assim sucessivamente.

Nesse ordenamento, os números e caracteres especiais comuns sempre antecedem as letras na questão de precedência, como você pode conferir na tabela ASCII ou UNICODE.

Isso causa um efeito contraintuitivo quando estamos tratando somente com números, como é o seu caso, pois 489 sempre aparecerá antes de 75 (porque 4 (U+0034) é menor do que 7 (U+0037)), por exemplo, e assim por diante.